# REST API Authentication for client-to-server and server-to-server

Tags: passport.js, public-key-encryption, api-key, passport-google-oauth

I have a REST api( nodejs+express+mongo) that is being consumed by two types of users:

1. End-user (Authenticated via website, mobile apps using google-signin).
2. Gateways/services that will consume the API programmatically.

My question is about what is the best way to handle authentication for the second type of user ?
The users are stored in my database(linked to google-signin using their email-id)

The end-user creates gateways and services so I could provide an interface to manage credentials for that.(For example if I use API Keys or public-private key pair, then the user could use the website to add/remove credentials for gateways/services).

I am using passport-google-oauth2 Strategy to handle authentication for the first case.  What would be the best way to handle authentication for the second type of consumer ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, OAuth is an authorization protocol, not an authentication protocol. Google authentication is performed within a web login session, so I'm not clear how that would work for you in conjunction with a REST client.

Unfortunately there are many ways you could approach your problem, depending on how much code you want to write vs how many existing services you want to use instead and how you intend to do your user management.

Comment: I understand OAuth is an authorization protocol. I meant I am using it to authenticate users of my rest API. I guess I should have used the word google-signin instead of googe-oauth.
My question is about how to do authentication for my other type of consumers of rest api which are devices and services. They will be using the api programmatically. I am managing users in my database(for google sign-in, I use emailid to link to the database user entry). I am also writing a separate authorization layer.  So if there was an existing solution to handle authentication, I would prefer to use that.